# How to display animals with all information?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have four Tables. "Animals", "races", "animal_classes" and "animal_class_race".

Races and animal_classes are boring, only with "id" and "name".

The "animal_class_race" has: "id", "race_id", and "animal_class_id". Let us say: 1, 1, 1, and the timestamps

In "animal"-Table I have "id", "name" and "animal_class_race_id". Let us say: 1, bello, 1

What is the best way to show this animal with information from "race" and "animal_class"?

Comment: can you post your SQL tables and relatations

Answer (score 0):

```
select animals.name as name, races.name as race, animal_classes.name as animal_class from animals a inner join animal_class_race acr on a.animal_class_race_id = acr.id inner join races r on r.id = acr.race_id inner join animal_classes ac on ac.id = acr.animal_class_id order by a.name
```